# The git process never exits when running as a Python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, subprocess, git-lfs

### Background

I'm writing a Python program to process LFS error messages as I have some repos with missing LFS files in Bitbucket Server. The output when running `git lfs fetch --all` isn't very helpful when you want to find out which LFS files are missing from a repo. That's why I'm making a tool for it. Maybe it can be contributed back to the git project in some form when I'm done with it?

### Code snippet

```py
import subprocess

def git_lfs_fetch(repo_dir) -> list:
    timeout_sec = 120
    try:
        completed_process = subprocess.run(
            ["git", "lfs", "fetch", "--all"], check=False, cwd=repo_dir, 
            capture_output=True, text=True, timeout=timeout_sec, shell=False)
        return completed_process.stderr.split('\n')
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as ex:
        print(f'ERROR Could not complete "{ex.cmd}" before timeout of {timeout_sec} s!')
        print(ex.stderr)
        return []
```

### Problem

Sometimes, and not in any consistent way, the `subprocess.run()` method never returns because the `git-lfs` process never exits. Usually running the `git lfs fetch --all` command in my test repos takes a few seconds to complete. As a workaround, I added a 2 min `timeout` to the `subprocess.run()` call. I figured I could get the output I'm interested in from stderr from the exception, since the `git-lfs` was done with all it should do. However, that did not help. Python does not seem to be able to kill the `git` subprocess. I understand from the doc that it sends a `SIGKILL` to the process and then waits for it to exit. But it never exits, even with the timeout set.

If I manually kill the `git-lfs` process from the outside I get the expected output printed from `ex.stderr` so `git-lfs` sure looks like it is done, and my workaround does what it should.

### Environment

- `Windows 10, 64 bit`
- `Python 3.10.7`
- `git version 2.39.0.windows.2`

  - Upgraded from `2.35.2.windows.1`
- `git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf)`

  - Upgraded from `git-lfs/3.0.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.2)`

### Fixing my workaround

As I was writing this, in a typical [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) fashion, I had an idea.

Since Python fails to forcibly terminate the `git` subprocess I tried using `git-lfs` directly, instead of letting `git` call it. This made the timeout work.

```py
subprocess.run(["git-lfs", "fetch", "--all"], ...)
```

### What I'm looking for

The solution I'm looking for is a way to figure out why `git-lfs` and consequently `git` won't terminate properly. Even better would be a fix for that problem.

I have seen similar problems when calling `git` from Java and C# on both Linux and Windows (several years ago), i.e. the `git` command actually completes all it should do but the `git` process never terminates. So I'm thinking this "hanging" could be a problem in git itself. I really would like to be able to find out why the `git-lfs` process won't exit. I don't know where to start looking.

### Update

I used the tip from @CharlesDuffy to try `strace`. I got some output that did not really tell me anything useful.

In Task Manager I then happened to see that there was a few (7) ssh processes running. On inspection of their command line it became clear that they were related to Git LFS and that they all were waiting for a response from the Bitbucket Server. The commands issued to the server was one of these

- `ssh -p 7999 git@server-url "git-lfs-authenticate <path> download"`
- `ssh -p 7999 git@server-url "git-lfs-transfer <path> download"`

and they appeared to be left-over processes from all the times I had seen problems and forcibly killed the `git-lfs` process.

I upgraded Git to the latest version, 2.39.0 with git-lfs 3.3.0, and tried again. At first it seemed to work better but then I got `git-lfs` stuck again. This time running from the command line, not from Python, and Task Manager shows that `ssh.exe` is running this command line and seem stuck in it:

```bash
ssh -oControlMaster=Auto -oControlPath=C:\Users\username\Appdata\LocalTemp\sock-3553225979\sock-%C -p 7999 git@server-url "git-lfs-transfer <path> download"
```

I was unable to get any useful information from that hanging `ssh.exe` process using `strace` from `Git Bash`, and eventually it died while I was trying to get `strace` to attach to it again.

Since the `ssh` daemon on the server is living in the Bitbucket application I think the next step here is to involve Atlassian support for server side debugging. I still lack a reliable way of reproducing the problem though.

Comment: Have you used `strace` to look at what git or git-lfs is doing when it's hung? If it's stuck trying to read from stdin, f/e, then perhaps you might set `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: (you'll want to use the `-f` argument to follow forks so the trace watches subprocesses, the `-o` argument to write output to a file, and perhaps something like `-s 2048` to set a larger-than-default size for how much buffer content is included in the trace)

Answer (score -2):

By using this method

```
def git_lfs_fetch(repo_dir) -> list:
    timeout_sec = 120
    try:
        completed_process = subprocess.run(
            ["git", "lfs", "fetch", "--all"], check=False, cwd=repo_dir, 
            capture_output=True, text=True, timeout=timeout_sec, shell=False)
        return completed_process.stderr.split('\n')
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as ex:
        print(f'ERROR Could not complete "{ex.cmd}" before timeout of {timeout_sec} s!')
        print(ex.stderr)
        return []
```

Comment: Please add an English explanation of what you changed, why, and how it solves the problem.

Comment: (Moreover, the OP does already know how to make the timeout work; they're asking _why it happens_ and how to avoid needing it in the first place)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).